# Attribute erased once the instance is used in python

Tags: python, class, methods

I am starting with classes and instances in python. I have created a code in order to read a CSV file.

```
import csv

class FileOperations:

def __init__(self,file):
    self.archivo = file

def OpenFile(self):

    csv.register_dialect('EuroStats', delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    self.prereader = open(self.archivo,'r')  
    self.reader = csv.reader(self.prereader, dialect='EuroStats')
    return self.reader
class Lists:

def __init__(self,archivo):
    filehandler=FileOperations(archivo)
    self.lector = filehandler.OpenFile()


def CountryList(self):
    self.Ctries = []
    print('354')
    for row in self.lector:
        print('355')
        if row[2]=='01 Population' or row[2]== 'SUB-CHAPTER':
            self.Ctries.append(row[1])
            continue


    return self.Ctries


def PopRead(self,year):
    self.Pop=[]
    index=year-1955

    for row in self.lector:

        if row[2]=='01 Population' or row[2]== 'SUB-CHAPTER':
            self.Pop.append(row[index])

            continue

    return self.Pop
def main(name, data_dir='.'):

 Lista  = Lists('AMECO.csv') 


 d = Lista.CountryList()
 print(d)
 #Lista  = Lists('AMECO.csv') 
 e = Lista.PopRead(1962)
 print(e)      
if name=='main':
import sys
main(*sys.argv)
```

The problem comes, because the second list I try to create never fills up. It seems that 'self.lector' does not work again after creating one list. I am new to this, and I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Your indentation is rather broken. Please paste your code into the editor, select all the code as a block and use the `{}` toolbar button to indent all the code properly. Do *not* just fix up pasted code by only indenting a few of the lines.

Comment: You can't read from a file more than once unless you *rewind* the file to the start again with `fileobj.seek(0)`.